# PHP / HTML using two tables and get name to use in html table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a little problem, right now i'm making a little ticket system.

I have a table where it displayes available tickets created related to that user.

Example:
User Nick has 3 tickets and it gets displayed like that.

```
+-----------+------------+---------+
| Ticket ID | Created by | Comment |
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     2     |     4      |  Text   | <- Ticket 1
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     3     |     2      |  Text   | <- Ticket 2
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     5     |     3      |  Text   | <- Ticket 3
+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Right now, i have only the userid in the column 'created by' but i want the username to be displayed instead.

I have two database tables and all users are saved in table 1 and the tickets get saved in table 2, now I need a query to get the username of the userid 4,2,3 to display the username in the HTML table but i don't know how to do that.

My current query looks like this:

```
$pdo->query("BEGIN");
$t = ("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE uid='$param'");
$pdo->query("COMMIT");
```

To explane the 'uid', with the uid i get the tickets related to that player.

//Edit

That is not exactly that what i'm searching for, maybe i explained it a little bit wrong.

This is my ticket table:
[Ticket Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMOqX.png)

First row: Ticket ID
Second row: The UID identifes the user the ticket got created for
Third row: the ID of the user that created the ticket.

Now i have the user table:
[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNas7.png)

First row: Identifes the user
Third row: Is the username of the user

Now i have a html table(That's just a small part of the table):
[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk5Ex.png)

First row: The userid of the user created that ticket
Second row: The ticket ID

Right now it displays all the tickets created for UID 76561198073236987 and instead of displaying only the ID of the user created the ticket i want to display the username.

Comment: You need to join the two tables in the `FROM` clause. Something like: `SELECT user.name, ticket.ticketid, ticket.comment FROM user INNER JOIN ticket  ON user.uid = ticket.uid` using an `INNER JOIN` and specifying the relationship between the two joined tables in the join's `ON` clause

Comment: I don't see uid : " 76561198073236987 " On user table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own with following Query.

```
SELECT ticket.*, users.benutzername FROM ticket INNER JOIN users ON ticket.created_by=users.id WHERE uid='$param'
```

In this example i replaced all my results with a "*" to make this query shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Joints. See below query

```
"SELECT * FROM ticket
LEFT JOIN user ON user.uid= ticket.uid WHERE ticket.uid='$param'";
```

This will return user details alongside with ticket details.
 ticket details will be received either user is available or not
For more about left join :https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

If you want only the tickets which has user details, You can user inner-join or join. See below query

```
"SELECT * FROM ticket
    INNER JOIN user ON user.uid= ticket.uid WHERE ticket.uid='$param'";
```

This will return user details alongside with ticket details.
 ticket details will not be received if user is not available
For more about Inner join :https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I editited my post, that is not exactly that what i searched for

Comment: if you want to get user name from user Id, the only best solution is this. but you have to join it correctly. what is the column name that has this uid : " 76561198073236987 " on user table?

Comment: In  my user table is no column that contains the "UID". To make it more clear, the ticket system is a part of a support panel to administrate a gameserver, this gameserver also uses a database(different one) and with the "UID" you can identify a player that plays on that server. The support panel has an own database where all users are saved in and that users get identified with there "ID" you see on the picture. As you see in my query you get the UID of the player with "$param".